# Javascript not fully reloading page with new url parameter

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a webpage that shows the user different image galleries. There is a custom built dropdown that lists all of the different galleries to view, and when the user clicks on one it reloads the page with a different url parameter. The idea is that there is a separate file that preprocesses the page and runs a query with the different gallery id grabbed from the url, then sends the reloading page all of the image data to display.

The problem seems to be that the page doesn't do a full reload, just reloads the front end. So the url will update, but the query doesn't get run again. Right now I'm trying:

```
$('.gallery-option').click(function() {
    var nid = 257;
    if($(this).attr("rel").length) {
        nid = $(this).attr("rel");
    }
    var url = location.origin + '/image_galleries?library=' + nid;
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

The page 'appears' to refresh but none of the data gets refreshed.
However when I include a var_dump in my preprocess code, something about that seems to force the backend to run and everything works fine. So I guess my question is: Is there any way for javascript to refresh everything on the backend?

Comment: looks like browser cache

Answer (score 0):

A quick thought that comes to mind would be to check if the images are coming in through an AJAX request.  The following snippet could help you.

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){
    console.log("AJAX request successfully completed");
});
```

Another thought would be to use a similar implementation to the code you posted, but implement it inside a setInterval.
Clear the interval when original href !== location.href.

I hope this helps...